# Get the MIDI tempo from a Lilypond score in Scheme

Tags: lilypond

I have a set of Scheme functions that generate several MIDI files from a score. It does so by creating a book with several scores. I would like to have those MIDI files use the same MIDI setup as specified in the \midi{} block in the original score. Especially the tempo. Can that be extracted somehow? I know how to display the structure of music expressions and get properties, but Score is not a music expression. If I print it, I just get #, and I don't know what that means. I have read through the documentation but found no guide on how to traverse the structure of a #.

Does anyone have insights into working with scores from Scheme?

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like this:

```
\context {
      \Score
      \include "midi-score-setup.lyi"
}
```

And put smth like `tempoWholesPerMinute = #(ly:make-moment 18)` in that file.

So you can put a required the same tempo in a single file and change it over there as you wish.